# Faster way of implementing pd.replace on subset of columns

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

```
def replace_inf(df):
     all_columns = list(df.columns)
     no_infs = ['some_col', 'some_col']
     inf_cols = [c for c in all_columns if c not in no_infs]
     replace = [np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]
     for col in inf_cols:
        df[col] = df[col].replace(replace, 0, regex=True)
        df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float32)
```

Currently this is taking 3s for a subset of my columns and many times that for all columns. I think map, apply, lambda and vectorize could help but I'm having trouble writing something that works.

Comment: I don't think `replace` is the problem. I'd think `.astype` is more likely the culprit here. you can do `df[inf_cols] = df[inf_cols].replace(replace,0).astype(np.float32)`. Remove the `regex=True` because you are replacing the actual cell value, not the substrings.

Comment: @QuangHoang As written it's taking 3s. Removing `.astype(np.float32)` gets me down to 1.6s. Chaining `.astype()`, as you suggest, gets 1.8s. Removing `regex=True` gets me down to 1.7s. Thank you!  1.7s is still too slow, however, as I have 50x the number of cols in full data and 30,000 such dfs to manipulate. Any thoughts on how to get rid of that for loop?

Comment: @Ahmed What are the values in columns? just numbers and nan/inf? Or strings?

Comment: You could try `pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce', downcast='float')` then `df[col].fillna(0)`.

Comment: @Ahmed You don't need to loop through the columns. I wrote `df[inf_cols] = df[inf_cols]...` without the `for col in inf_cols` loops.

Comment: @AndrejKesely just numbers and np.infs

Comment: @Ahmed How many rows/columns are in one df? I assume it's some big number, if the duration is ~2 seconds

Comment: @QuangHoang Removing the for loop and just using `df[inf_cols] = df[inf_cols]` takes it down from 1.7s to 1.1s. Thank you again! But can we go faster!?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I'm in the process of feature engineering 30,000 samples which are dfs. I have 10-100 rows for each sample and around 100 features that I am blowing out to anywhere from 5k columns to 150k columns (rolls, shifts, division). The final number of cols all depends on how quickly I can get this replace accomplished - which is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) and parallelize the task:

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def _replace_inf_nb(m):
    for col in nb.prange(m.shape[1]):
        for row in range(m.shape[0]):
            v = m[row, col]
            if np.isinf(v) or np.isnan(v):
                m[row, col] = 0
    return m


def replace_inf_numba(df):
    all_columns = list(df.columns)
    no_infs = ["col4"]  # columns to not replace
    inf_cols = [c for c in all_columns if c not in no_infs]
    df.loc[:, inf_cols] = _replace_inf_nb(df[inf_cols].values)
```

Benchmark (using dataframe 5000 columns/100 rows - with random 10 NaNs/10 inf/10 -inf in each column):

```py
from timeit import timeit

import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def get_df(n_col, N, num_nan=1_000, num_inf=1_000, num_ninf=1_000):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {f"col{n}": np.random.random(size=N) * 10 for n in range(1, n_col + 1)}
    )

    for c in df.columns:
        df.loc[np.random.randint(0, N, size=num_nan), c] = np.nan
        df.loc[np.random.randint(0, N, size=num_inf), c] = np.inf
        df.loc[np.random.randint(0, N, size=num_ninf), c] = -np.inf

    return df


def replace_inf(df):
    all_columns = list(df.columns)
    no_infs = ["col4"]
    inf_cols = [c for c in all_columns if c not in no_infs]
    replace = [np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf]
    df[inf_cols] = df[inf_cols].replace(replace, 0)


@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def _replace_inf_nb(m):
    for col in nb.prange(m.shape[1]):
        for row in range(m.shape[0]):
            v = m[row, col]
            if np.isinf(v) or np.isnan(v):
                m[row, col] = 0
    return m


def replace_inf_numba(df):
    all_columns = list(df.columns)
    no_infs = ["col4"]  # columns to not replace
    inf_cols = [c for c in all_columns if c not in no_infs]
    df.loc[:, inf_cols] = _replace_inf_nb(df[inf_cols].values)


df1 = get_df(50_000, 100, num_nan=10, num_inf=10, num_ninf=10)
df2 = df1.copy()

replace_inf(df1)
replace_inf_numba(df2)

assert np.allclose(df1, df2, equal_nan=True)

t1 = timeit(
    "replace_inf(df)",
    setup="df = get_df(5000, 100, num_nan=10, num_inf=10, num_ninf=10)",
    globals=globals(),
    number=1,
)

t2 = timeit(
    "replace_inf_numba(df)",
    setup="df = get_df(5000, 100, num_nan=10, num_inf=10, num_ninf=10)",
    globals=globals(),
    number=1,
)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my computer (AMD 5700x):

```
0.41479378099757014
0.004868026000622194
```

With 50_000 columns/100 rows:

```
12.89557717199932
0.04892206600197824
```

With 150_000 columns/100 rows:

```
95.10914388500532
0.13103608299570624
```

Comment: What is this black magic? Will try and report back. Many thanks - about 50 days of processing thanks : )

Comment: @Ahmed I'm assuming the big number of columns is the problem - `pandas` creates for each column a `pd.Series` which takes time. `numba` just processes numpy arrays (and in parallel fashion), which is fast

Comment: @Ahmed Also you can try `df.loc[:, inf_cols] = df[inf_cols].replace(replace, 0)` (seems it's a lot faster than `df[inf_cols] = df[inf_cols].replace(replace, 0)`, but still, `numba` is 2x faster here)

Comment: I have it working. Numba is wild. 3s ----> .055s. Have to rewrite the rest in Numba.